# How to split rows based on date from mySQL and display it using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I save the visits and the time of users in my page. The mySQL is like below:

```
id  - user - page - timestamp
340 - 1 - page1 - 2009-05-18 22:11:11
339 - 1 - page3 - 2009-05-18 22:10:01
338 - 2 - page4 - 2009-05-18 22:08:05
337 - 1 - page2 - 2009-05-18 22:06:00
336 - 2 - page1 - 2009-05-18 22:15:10
...
...
280 - 1 - page5 - 2009-05-17 14:10:10
279 - 2 - page 3 - 2009-05-17 12:05:00
```

How can I have the below output, with use of PHP ?

**Expected outpout** `(show.php?user=1)`

**2009-05-18**

```
page 1 - 2009-05-18 22:11:11 last page
page3 - 2009-05-18 22:10:01 stayed for 1 minute 10 seconds
page2 - 2009-05-18 22:06:00 stayed for 4 minutes 1 second
```

**2009-05-17**

```
page 5 - 2009-05-17 14:10:10 last page
page 3 - 2009-05-17 12:05:00 stayed for 2 hours 5 minutes 10 seconds
```

**What I have done until now**

```
$sql= mysql_query(SELECT user, page, timestamp FROM paths WHERE DATE(`date`) = '2009-05-18'); // must not set a date, but get all the dates

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo $row["page"]. " - " . $row["timestamp"]. "<br>";
//echo this timestamp - previous timestamp
//if different day then start again
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this?

Comment: @b0s3 I can have the result with sql if I set manually the date. But I do not know how to let the system get all the available dates and split them.

Comment: If you have tried anything then show us.

Comment: @b0s3 I hae updated my question with example

Answer (score 0):

Actually i have a idea for this but it is not usefull for time;

```
sql = "SELECT user, page, timestamp FROM paths WHERE DATE(`date`) = '2009-05-18')" ORDER BY page ASC,timestamp DESC;

$a = null;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $a[] = $row;
}

$i = 0;

while(i<sizeof($a)){
    if($a[i]->page == $a[i+1]->page){
        $sub = (int) $a[i+1]->timestamp - (int) $a[i]->timestamp;
        echo '' .$a[i]->page. '-' .$a[i]->timestamp.' stayed for '.$sub. 'miliseconds';
    }
    i = i+2;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for this, I will try it. However it is supposed not to provide the dates, but to get automatically all the dates a user has records

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I haven't tested. But it should work. If any error means let me know..

```
// query to fetch the dates first.
$date_query = mysql_query ( "SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(timestamp)) FROM paths order by timestamp asc;" );

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array ( $date_query ) ) {
    echo "<h1>".$row ['timestamp']."</h1><br/>";
    // query to fetch the related datas based on the date from the table.
    $related_day_result = mysql_query("SELECT * from path where DATE(timestamp) = '".$row['timestamp']."'");
    while ( $results = mysql_fetch_array ( $related_day_result ) ) {
        echo $results ["page"] . " - " . $results ["timestamp"] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This query does almost all what u need ... [SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab9c2/1)

```
SELECT page,max(`timestamp`) `timestamp` from paths
group by date(`timestamp`),page order by `timestamp` desc
```

**But** if you need to show the **stayed time**.. then **calculation** is needed. If any query about calculation. I am there to explain

```
$sql = "SELECT page,max(`timestamp`) `timestamp` from paths
group by date(`timestamp`),page order by `timestamp` desc";

$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$lastDate = null;
$diff = 'last page';
$lastVisitTime = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $time = strtotime($row['timestamp']);
    $thisDate = date('Y-m-d',$time);
    //echo "   ".$thisDate;

    if($lastDate == $thisDate)
    {
        $date1 = new DateTime($lastVisitTime);
        $date2 = new DateTime($row['timestamp']);
        $interval = $date2->diff($date1);
        $diff = "  stayed ". $interval->h . " hours ".$interval->i . " minutes ".$interval->s." seconds";

        /*other method
        $time1 = $lastVisitTime;
        $time2 = $row['timestamp'];
        $sec_diff = strtotime($time1) - strtotime($time2);
        $hourdiff = (int)($sec_diff/3600);
        $diff = $hourdiff .' hours ';*/

        $lastVisitTime = $row['timestamp'];
    }
    else
    {
        $diff = 'last page';
        $lastDate = $thisDate;
        $lastVisitTime = $row['timestamp'];
    }

    echo $row['page']." ___ ".$row['timestamp']." ___ ". $diff.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tested it and it works great. However, can you please make it more clearly when the dates are split? meaning each different day to have `<br> date`

Comment: Could not understand.. Echo statement at the end of loop gives you different date (for each iteration) so I put `<br>` in that only echo. You can come with some desired output so i could follow, as we have done earlier. Current answer is resulting the output expected by question